# Applescript open app

Tags: macos, applescript

When I create a new Applescript project in Xcode and I run the app it opens the app window but when I close the app on the cross and click on the app again in the dock (still running) it doesn't shows up again. I have to close it in the menu or right click at it in the dock and close it from running. How can I open it again when the app is still running?

Answer (score 2):

- When you click on the red (close) button in a standard Cocoa window you are going to close the main window but you don't quit the application. This is independent of the programming language. If you want to quit the application implement `applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed` and return `true`.
- When you click on the dock icon, no window is open and your application is document based, a new document window is opened. In a standard app nothing will happen. To show the main window you have to implement `applicationShouldHandleReopen:hasVisibleWindows:`, call `window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)` and return `false`.